# Neo4j Community Server: Cannot select my database in the remote interface

Tags: neo4j

I'm still relativly neew to Neo4j and especially new to the neo4j community server 4. So please forgive me if I am just dumb here.

I am using the neo4j-community-4.3.2 server and imported my data via the neo4j-admin import:

```
bin/neo4j-admin import --database=dicom --skip-duplicate-nodes --skip-bad-relationships --nodes=...
```

(so I named the database "dicom")

So far so good. Everything until here works fine:

```
IMPORT DONE in 42s 16ms. 
Imported:
  81656 nodes
  694772 relationships
  2252244 properties
```

When I wanted to start the database with `./bin/neo4j console` it worked as well:

```
Directories in use:
home:         /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2
config:       /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/conf
logs:         /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/logs
plugins:      /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/plugins
import:       /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/import
data:         /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/data
certificates: /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/certificates
licenses:     /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/licenses
run:          /Users/tobias/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Documents/Uni/Masterarbeit/Neo4j/neo4j-community-4.3.2/run
Starting Neo4j.
2021-08-06 10:53:47.901+0000 INFO  Starting...
2021-08-06 10:53:49.310+0000 INFO  ======== Neo4j 4.3.2 ========
2021-08-06 10:53:53.761+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@3da61af2
2021-08-06 10:53:53.765+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@54530644
2021-08-06 10:53:53.765+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@42734b71
2021-08-06 10:53:53.846+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@726d8fa0
2021-08-06 10:53:53.866+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@666b1244
2021-08-06 10:53:53.888+0000 INFO  org.neo4j.internal.kernel.api.security.AbstractSecurityLog$SecurityLogLine@789d8fd6
2021-08-06 10:53:56.919+0000 INFO  Bolt enabled on localhost:7687.
2021-08-06 10:53:57.446+0000 INFO  Remote interface available at http://localhost:7474/
2021-08-06 10:53:57.447+0000 INFO  Started.
```

So I thought it had worked. I opened http://localhost:7474/ in my browser to work with the database but apparently since neo4j community 4 there are multiple databases. In the dropdown menu I've got one named "neo4j" and one named "system" but unfortunately none named "dicom". What did I do wrong? Why can't I see my dicom database there? in the Neo4j directory NEO4J_HOME/data/databases there is a folder called "dicom" which seems to have the same files as the folders "neo4j" and "system".

Does anyone have any ideas? I'd be very grateful! Sorry for the very long post, I just wanted to be thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look for this configuration in <neo4j_home_dir>/conf/neo4j.conf file. Then change it to

```
 old: dbms.default_database=neo4j

 New: dbms.default_database=dicom
```

Then restart your neo4j instance.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much! You really saved my day mate!

Comment: Glad to help! Goodluck on your project.